# Summarize grouped/filtered data in google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am very new to web tools and javascript. So please excuse for some noob questions.

I am using Google Visualization dashboard using external data. I have a CategoryFilter control and displaying a table, column chart and a summary table.

With help from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16128770/grand-total-in-google-visualization-dashboard-table) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21815448/google-visualization-chartwrapper-group-columns-view/21895063#21895063) and lots of queries answered by user [@jmac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1933347/jmac) and [@asgallant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/613559/asgallant), I was able to come this far and make this working example - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udDLs/1/).

The code:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(proxyTable, 'ready', function () {
var group = google.visualization.data.group(proxyTable.getDataTable(), [{
// we need a key column to group on, but since we want all rows grouped     into 1, 
// then it needs a constant value
column: 0,
type: 'number',
modifier: function () {
return 1;
}
}], [{
// get the Avg GDP
column: 19,
type: 'number',
aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg
}, 
{
// get the Max Population
column: 9,
type: 'number',
aggregation: google.visualization.data.max
}, 
{
// get the # of -ve growth years
column: 21,
type: 'number',
aggregation: google.visualization.data.count
}]);

document.getElementById('AvgGDP').innerHTML = group.getValue(0, 1);
document.getElementById('Population').innerHTML = group.getValue(0, 2);
document.getElementById('GDPGrowth').innerHTML = group.getValue(0, 3);
});

// var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,###'});
// formatter.format(Population, 0); // Apply formatter to second column
```

The Problem:

[image: Summary]

Q1. As you can see, the summary table is unruly. Population field has big numbers, which is difficult to read. Similarly, Avg GDP has too many decimals. I am unable to format the fields. If I use this code, the chart does not display at all!

```
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({pattern: '#,###'});
    formatter.format(Population, 0); // Apply formatter to second column
```

How to use the format function? What am I doing wrong here?

Q2. I would like to display count of negative growth. How to get a condition to count for negative values in column 21?

Q3. How to use math function to calculate (avg of column 19)*(sum of column 21) ?

Q4.  I am unable to populate the summary in a Google chart Table. Hence used a bootstrap table. Can somebody guide me how to populate a table with summarized values? This is not essential though.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatters work on DataTables, so in this case you want to call `formatter.format` on the DataTable `group`, not `Population`:

```
formatter.format(group, 0);
```

Then when retrieving the data, if you want the formatted values, call the `getFormattedValue` method instead of the `getValue` method:

```
document.getElementById('AvgGDP').innerHTML = group.getFormattedValue(0, 1);
```

Getting a count of negative values will require a custom aggregation function, like this:

```
{
    // get the # of -ve growth years
    column: 21,
    type: 'number',
    aggregation: function (values) {
        var count = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i] < 0) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

To answer the last two parts together, you should be able to create a Table based on the DataTable `group`, and use the `view` parameter of the ChartWrapper object to calculate your products:

```
var summaryTable = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'summaryDiv',
    dataTable: group,
    options: {
        // summary table options
    }
    view: {
        columns: [1, 2, 3, {
            type: 'number',
            label: 'column label',
            calc: function (dt, row) {
                var val = dt.getValue(row, 1) * dt.getValue(row, 3);
                return {v: val, f: formatter.formatValue(val)};
            }
        }]
    }
});
summary.draw();
```

Comment: Hi @asgallant, thanks for quick help. The -ve count works like a charm. Thanks a ton. However, I could not work out formatter part of it. Now the charts says, "One or more participants failed to draw()". As  advised on other posts here, checked with browser's inspect element. It says - "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery'". I have updated the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udDLs/2/). If I don't use formatter, it works fine. Guess, I am doing something terribly wrong with it. Have tried all combinations but could not figure out what? Please help.

Comment: Hi again. Got the solution working. Missed out on the application of formatter.format(group, 1). Updated the working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/udDLs/3/). Thank you once again @asgallant. You are God!